# Set values for v-select items

Tags: laravel, vuetify.js

I've form.blade.php file , here's it's content

```
<app-add-new-file-form inline-template :subjects="{{ json_encode($subjects) }}">
    <v-form method="POST" action=" {{ route('files.store') }} " enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf
        <div class="my-8">
            <v-select v-model="subject" :items="subjects" :item-value="subject" name="subject" menu-props="auto"
                label="Subject" hide-details single-line></v-select>
            <p class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('subject') }}</p>
        </div>
    </v-form>
</app-add-new-file-form>
```

and in my vue components I've this code below :

```
<script>
export default {
  props: ["subjects"],
  data: () => {
    return {
      subject: "",
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

However, when i submit the form, the subject value is set to null on any subject I select

Note : the subjects array comes from laravel then I encode it to json.

Answer (score 0):

It is stated that Vuetify v-select does not have an input value. Longer answer by Vuetify dev [here](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/1565). They are just not setting the value to input.

The solution would be to add a hidden input that keeps the selected value and is submitted with form.

Example [codepen](https://codepen.io/LaCertosus/pen/OJJNoGx?editors=1010)

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    subjects: ['Subject1', 'Subject2', 'Subject3', 'Subject4'],
    selectedSubject: ''
  }),
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid>
      <v-row align="center">
        <v-col class="d-flex" cols="12" sm="6">
          <v-select
            v-model="selectedSubject"
            :items="subjects"
            label="Subjects"
            solo
          ></v-select>
          <input type="hidden" v-model="selectedSubject" name="subject">
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

I included an example image where to find input value from devtools. If you check v-select input value, it is empty. Then of you check the hidden inputs value it has the selected value.

[Example image where to find input value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6WGo.png)

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way to associate the value with v-select ?

Comment: As you can see from above example the v-model for both v-select and hidden input is "selectedSubject". This will connect selected value with your hidden input.